# Prevent gulp-inline-css from wrapping HTML content into html and body tags

Tags: html, gulp

I just want to work on a piece of HTML, which I want to later copy paste as it is and insert into an existing HTML document. I have something like this:

```
<div id="someDiv">
</div>
<script src="js/someScript.js" inline></script>
<style>
    div#someDiv {
        font-weight: bold;
    }
</style>
```

I am using gulp-inline-source to get the script in the built file, I do some basic html minification.
Here is my gulpfile.js:

```
var gulp = require('gulp');
var del = require('del');
var jshint = require('gulp-jshint');
var inlinesource = require('gulp-inline-source');
var htmlmin = require('gulp-htmlmin');
var inlineCss = require('gulp-inline-css');

gulp.task('clean', function(cb) {
    del(['assets/*'], cb)
});

gulp.task('lint', function() {
    return gulp.src('./src/js/*.js')
        .pipe(jshint())
        .pipe(jshint.reporter('default'));
});

gulp.task('inlinesource-htmlmin', function() {
    return gulp.src('./src/*.html')
        .pipe(inlinesource())
        .pipe(inlineCss())
        .pipe(htmlmin({collapseWhitespace: true}))
        .pipe(gulp.dest('./assets'));
});

gulp.task('default', ['clean', 'lint', 'inlinesource-htmlmin']);
```

It looks like gulp-inline-css is wrapping my content into html and body tags because it does not happen when I comment out the .pipe(inlineCss()) line.

Here is what I get:

```
<html><body><div id="someDiv" style="font-weight: bold"></div><script>$(document).ready(function(){console.log("logging")});</script></body></html>
```

Any idea how I could prevent that from happening?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ended up using [gulp-replace](https://www.npmjs.org/package/gulp-replace) to remove the tags after inlineCss like this:

```
var gulp = require('gulp');
var del = require('del');
var jshint = require('gulp-jshint');
var inlinesource = require('gulp-inline-source');
var htmlmin = require('gulp-htmlmin');
var inlineCss = require('gulp-inline-css');
var replace = require('gulp-replace')

gulp.task('clean', function(cb) {
    del(['assets/*'], cb)
});

gulp.task('lint', function() {
    return gulp.src('./src/js/*.js')
        .pipe(jshint())
        .pipe(jshint.reporter('default'));
});

gulp.task('inlinesource-htmlmin', function() {
    return gulp.src('./src/*.html')
        .pipe(inlinesource())
        .pipe(inlineCss())
        .pipe(replace(/<(html|body)>/g, ''))
        .pipe(htmlmin({collapseWhitespace: true}))
        .pipe(gulp.dest('./assets'));
});

gulp.task('default', ['clean', 'lint', 'inlinesource-htmlmin']);
```